# Javascript rowIndex method is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the rowIndex property of TR but it is not working. Please let me know if i am doing something wrong here.

```
function myMethod(){
                alert ( this.parent.rowIndex  );   // parentNode is also used
            }
```

Html

```
<table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td onclick="myMethod();">1.1</td>
                <td>1.2</td>
                <td>1.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="myMethod();">2.1</td>
                <td>2.2</td>
                <td>2.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="myMethod();">3.1</td>
                <td>3.2</td>
                <td>3.3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="myMethod();">4.1</td>
                <td>4.2</td>
                <td>4.3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the "this" in this.parent.rowIndex is the window. Not the td element.
Try

```
<td onclick="myMethod(this);">1.1</td>

function myMethod(obj){ alert ( obj.parentNode.rowIndex );}
```

Comment: I was writing an answer, but I like this one well enough so I won't bother. By way of further explanation, though, I will point out that the `this` keyword refers to the context in which it appears, not the context that the function was called from.

Comment: `parent` does not exist, it should be `parentNode`

Comment: I have done the exact same way, But that returns me as "Undefined". Someone please help.

Answer (score 2):

How about like this?

```
<td onclick="myMethod(this);">1.1</td>
```

...

```
function myMethod(obj){
    alert ( obj.parentNode.rowIndex  );   // parentNode is also used
}
```

Comment: @Pranav-BitWiser, of course, this question and answers are not about return values, but the scope of 'this'.

Answer (score 2):

Others have beaten me to why your code isn't working (concerning the value of `this` and the `parentNode` attribute), but I would still like to point out that **event attachment via HTML attributes is antiquated and wrong.**

You should use one of the prevalent JavaScript libraries like jQuery, Dojo, YUI, Prototype, ExtJs, or Mootools to attach the event in a to ensure that your your page structure is decoupled from the event logic.  Here's a simple example using jQuery:

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $(".row").click(function() {
        alert( $(this).parent().attr("rowIndex") );
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="row">1.1</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>1.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="row">2.1</td>
        <td>2.2</td>
        <td>2.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="row">3.1</td>
        <td>3.2</td>
        <td>3.3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="row">4.1</td>
        <td>4.2</td>
        <td>4.3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I also suggest learning the details of JavaScript in general, but at any rate, good luck.

Comment: Agree that you should avoid event attributes, but there's no need to go straight to listeners or frameworks just for event binding. `td.onclick= function() { ... }` is fine for the common case where you only need one event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <script>
    function myMethod(e){
                            alert('am in');
                            alert(e.parent);
                            alert ( e.innerHTML);   // parentNode is also used
                    }
    </script>


    <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                            <td onclick="myMethod(this);">1.1</td>
                            <td>1.2</td>
                            <td>1.3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td onclick="myMethod();">2.1</td>
                            <td>2.2</td>
                            <td>2.3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td onclick="myMethod();">3.1</td>
                            <td>3.2</td>
                            <td>3.3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td onclick="myMethod();">4.1</td>
                            <td>4.2</td>
                            <td>4.3</td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            </body>
            </html>
```

the value of e which is basically the TD object does not have property as parent and thus it is coming as undefined.

I think you need to search for tr via getElementById and give some unqiue ID to TD so that td can provide its corresponding tr id and then you can get that TR.

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_td.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$('#datatable').on("click", ".add18", function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var rowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    alert(rowIndex);
});
```