# how to call [object htmlDivElement]

Tags: javascript

i want to call the functions **movein(this)** & **moveout(this)** directly with out using onmouseover or onmouseout
by the way (**this**) is [object htmlDivElement]

```
  var tb = '<div id="' + o.id + '" onmouseover="movein(this);" onmouseout="moveout(this);"><div><table>\n';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried `movein(document.getElementById(o.id))` & `moveout(document.getElementById(o.id))` ?

Comment: but there is a table ... can you rewrite the hole code?
 thanks

Comment: All you really need to take care of is passing the right id (of the element you want) to _document.getElementById_. Whether it's a DIV or TABLE doesn't really matter, unless _movein_ / _moveout_ expects a certain kind

Answer (score 1):

Using *event delegation* may be an option for you, see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824206/how-to-detect-which-row-tr-is-clicked/1824700#1824700). Using event delegation, you define a mouseover/-out handler on the table and let the handler decide if and what action has to be taken.