# Figure out which row in an HTML table was clicked

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect which row [ tr ] is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824206/how-to-detect-which-row-tr-is-clicked)

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

In JavaScript (no jQuery please) how do I work out if a user clicks on the table on which row he/she clicked?

Comment: isn't this thread the same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824206/how-to-detect-which-row-tr-is-clicked

Comment: Give your rows an `id` attribute and hook up the onclick event

Comment: Niiiighhh. Use a library. It doesn't need to be jQuery (and jQuery wouldn't even be my first choice), but use a library. Dealing with this sort of relatively complex event logic has enough variances between browsers to be annoying. Use existing code to solve the problem instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Quentin: I would hardly call this complex event logic

Comment: Sticking an event handler on the table, figuring out the clicked element (in the two different major event models), then walking up the DOM until you find a table row? It is *sufficiently* complex to justify a library.

Comment: @Quentin: OR, you simply iterate over all the table rows adding a listener to each row. If you can't do iteration, then I'm not sure you need to be dabbling in event-driven programming yet.

Comment: @Quentin: use a library... reinventing the wheel... Why do some people infer too much from a simple question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function handleEvent(e) {
  // Do stuff with the row
}

var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var row in rows) {
  row.addEventListener('click', handleEvent); 
  // or attachEvent, depends on browser
}
```

Comment: Internet Explorer didn't support the standard event model until recently. Think it was version 9, but might have been a bit earlier. Still, this will break in many places.

Comment: @Quentin: What? If you mean it doesn't support `addEventListener`, I absolutely agree - that's why I put the comment in there. Otherwise, what did you mean by your comment?

Comment: Ah, missed that. This is going to error when it tries to call `row.length.addEventListener` or `row.item.addEventListener` though.

Comment: @Quentin: You have a point there - to correctly do it you would have to call `hasOwnProperty` or do a `for (i ; i < length; i++)` loop - ESPECIALLY if you are using Prototype

Answer (score 4):

[event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target), [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName), [traditional event method](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html):

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
     trs[i].onclick = clickHandler;   
}

function clickHandler(event) {
    alert(this.innerText || this.textContent);  // edit: textContent for firefox support
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J8fYW/1)

Comment: +1 Simple and easy. You'll just want `alert(this.innerText || this.textContent);` to pick up Firefox support.

Answer (score 3):

If you attach a click event handler to the table, you can get the event `target`, which will contain the element that was actually clicked:

```
document.getElementById("yourTable").onclick = function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);   
}
```

In your example, that's likely to be a `td`, so you could access the `tr` like this:

```
var tr = e.target.parentNode;
```

You can check the type of element that has been clicked with the `tagName` property:

```
var clickedElementType = e.target.tagName; //Returns something like "TD"
```

Alternatively, you could iterate over all the `tr` elements in your table and bind a click event handler to each.

Comment: Internet Explorer didn't support the standard event model until recently. Think it was version 9, but might have been a bit earlier. Still, this will break in many places.

Comment: True. I'm not going to go into all the differences though. As you already said, just use a library! (And I'm pretty sure you're right, it was version 9).

Comment: `var tr = (e||window.event)[e?'target':'srcElement'].parentNode` should take care of IE nicely.

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onload = function(){
  var table = document.getElementById('myTableID');
  table.addEventListener('click',test,false);
}

function test(e){
  var element = e.srcElement || e.target;
  if(element.nodeName == 'TABLE') return;

  while(element.nodeName != 'TR') element = element.parentNode;
  alert(element.rowIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to attach an event to the DOM element vs setting onclick. You'll have to do some checking if you want it to work with IE:

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
var len = trs.length

var clickHandler = function(i){
    alert('clicked');
};

for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    var theRow = trs[i];

    if(theRow.addEventListener){
        theRow.addEventListener('click',clickHandler);
    }
    else{
        theRow.attachEvent('onclick',clickHandler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an id to each row and then you can query the node id from the Javascript onclick() handler

Answer (score 1):

How about putting an onClick on the `<tr>`?